# codeigniter session lost when refresh (F5)

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, redirect

First of all i'm new for codeigniter. All i want to ask is, why every refresh my session data is lost. i redirect to login.

Here is my code.

login controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->view('login');
    }

}

?>
```

verifylogin

```
function index() {
  //This method will have the credentials validation
  $this->load->library('form_validation');

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

  if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
    //$this->load->view('headerx');
    //redirect('login', 'refresh'); 
    $this->load->view('login');
  }
  else {
    //Go to private area
    redirect('home');
  }

}

function check_database($password) {
  //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
  $username = $this->input->post('username');

  //query the database
  $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);

  if($result) {
    $sess_array = array();
    foreach($result as $row) {
      $sess_array = array(
        'id' => $row->id,
        'username' => $row->username
      );
      $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
    }
    return TRUE;
  }
  else {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
    return false;
  }
}
?>
```

home controller

```
function index()
{
  if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
    $this->load->view('home', $data);
  }
  else {
    //If no session, redirect to login page
    // print_r($this->session->all_userdata()); 
    //die();
    redirect('login');
  }
}
```

first login it is success, but when i refresh (f5) it is back to login form.
my opinion its because session is lost.
thanks for any help...

**EDIT AND SOLVED :**

sorry for inconvenience, this problem happen because

```
<script>
    function goOut(){
        <?php $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');?>   
        window.location="<?php echo base_url()?>";    
    }
</script>
```

my purpose it is when click button logout, then session is unset, but if i input in the header, session will be lost again, so i will find another way. thank you for your attentions and help.

Comment: Why do you think the session is lost? Have you checked it's lost?

Comment: Yes, i've already check with print_r($this->session->userdata('logged_in')); in top of condition. first is appears but when i refresh it is blank

Comment: Could you also post your configuration file as well?

Comment: $config['sess_cookie_name']  = 'ci_session';
    $config['sess_expiration']  = 7200;
    $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
    $config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
    $config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;
    $config['sess_table_name']  = 'ci_sessions';
    $config['sess_match_ip']  = FALSE;
    $config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
    $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;

Answer (score 1):

I would try using CodeIgniter's sessions in the database instead. I've had problems with CI in the past with this sort of problem. It usually occurs when you're setting a large amount of data (greater than 4KB) in the cookie.

Let me know if database-based sessions is not an option.

See here for more information: [CodeIgniter Sessions](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) See heading "Saving Session Data to a Database"

Comment: Agreed, DB sessions are the way to go

Comment: There could be an issue with duplicate sessions. Your prior session may not be destroyed properly and is causing a conflict when attempting to renew the current session. Does this problem occur in other browsers as well?

Comment: I have had similar problems with CI sessions, i found that https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/OB-Session works very well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows there is an issue with Codeigniter, PHP 7, and Apache on Windows 10. I had a client who wanted the staging application on their own laptop, and this only happened on their new laptop.

So after hours of testing, we uninstalled XAMPP 7.1.4, and reinstalled XAMPP with version 5.6.XX. And that fixed it. Yet, there were no issues on Linux boxes running Nginx and PHP 7. Just Windows 10.

Anyway, I hope this helps! It took me hours to find the solution.